# Matlab : running m-files by running another m-file

Tags: matlab

I would like to execute multi m-files by executing another m-file.

For example,

When I have two m-files like below,

a.m file in folder A,

```
% a.m file
val1=1;
save('val1.mat','val1')
```

And then, b.m file in folder B,

```
% b.m file
val2=2;
save('val2.mat','val2')
```

I would like to running the a.m file and b.m file by running c.m file, which is in folder C.

Possible code of c.m file would like below,

```
runMFIle('a.m', directory A);
runMFIle('b.m', directory B);
```

And then, val1.mat would be saved in folder A, while val2.mat would be saved in folder B.

Is it possible in matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. You just have to add `directory A` and `directory B` to the search path where MATLAB can find them. So inside your `c.m`, write

```
addpath('../DirA');
addpath('../DirB');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code. But I could not run a, b m-files by c.m. Could you provide more detail method?

Comment: addpath('C:\Users\Desktop\A');
addpath('C:\Users\Desktop\B'); I tried like this, error was none.

Comment: But, the files in the folders were not run.

Comment: With my two lines of code, you just add the directories A and B such that Matlab recognizes it. Now, you can run the scripts (or functions) a.m and b.m by adding the lines a; b; into the file c.m. So c.m should contain:
addpath('../DirA');
addpath('../DirB');
a;
b;

Comment: the result is slightly different with my concern but, not a big problem. It works. Thank you~

Comment: What is slightly different? What is not working exactly how you would like?

Comment: The final saved data are not in A and B folder, respectively, but in C folder. But, that's OK~

Comment: Yes, because you execute the save command from the C directory and if you don't give the saving path explicitly, Matlab will put them to the current directory (i.e. C). In a.m give explicitly `save('C:\Users\Desktop\A\val1.mat', 'val1');` and similarly in b.m: `save('C:\Users\Desktop\B\val2.mat', 'val2');`. Even better if you use relative file paths.

Comment: [`cd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html) is probably a better option for this situation. Being promiscuous with `addpath` is a great way to pollute your namespace and end up with unintended conflicts.